I don't get my own email if I send it using Gmail to Mailman
I have a Python Mailing list using Mailman2
When subscribed people using gmail send and email to the list, they don't get their own email. But if they reply, they get it.
It works using any other email.
How can I fix this issue?
I have checked and changed some settings but still can't find a solution.
